# Why does attr.disabled = "row?.statut === 'TRM' ? true: null"doesn't disabled the specific row?

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-directive, material-design

i want to disabled the rows that doen't match my criteria but the property doesn't return a single disabled row

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"  [class.disabled] = "row?.statut === 'TRM' ? true: null"></mat-row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can disable the click(if there is some selection event) and apply style to the row.

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
(click)="!row.statut"
[ngStyle]="row.statut && {'background-color': 'lightgrey'}">
```

[disable rows sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-disable-row-tlehuj?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.html)